# openEdge SmartToolBar Record Modification

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

in smartToolBar AddRecord,SaveRecord,CopyRecord ,DeleteRecord and cancel button always desabled.

Help me to ENABLE IT.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a smart link to a smart Data Object (Smart Query in V8)? And a link to the viewer/browse you're using?

Comment: I'm sorry, did that help in any way?

Comment: yes, actually i forgot to add tableio link. your hint reminds me. thanks again.